# upload files to Dropbox from iOS app with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox

I have completed this tutorial(https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/09/swift-apps-with-dropbox/) and successfully linked my iOS app with Dropbox. However, I want to be upload a file from my app to Dropbox. All the tutorials out there only have code in Objective C, including the main one from Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios). **Does anyone know how to do it with Swift?**

Thanks!

Comment: You could always use [Objective-C bridging headers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) to call into Objective-C code from Swift.

Comment: You might also take a look at SwiftyDropbox, the new Swift SDK for Dropbox API v2 (currently in preview): https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/05/try-out-swiftydropbox-the-new-swift-sdk-for-dropbox-api-v2/.

Answer (score 2):

It works.

```
let textContent = "Hello Swift Upload"

let textData:NSData? = textContent.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

var client:DropboxClient? = Dropbox.authorizedClient

if let cli = client {
    cli.files.upload(path: "/Swift-Upload.txt", mode: Files.WriteMode.Add, autorename: false, clientModified: nil, mute: false, body: textData!)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS 10.12.3 swift 3.0 SwiftyDropbox 4.1.1 A slightly more complete answer a year on.

```
 func files_saver(sourcePath: String) {
    let textContent = "Blah Blah Blah"
    let textData:NSData? = textContent.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) as NSData?

    let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient!
    client.files.upload(path: sourcePath, input: textData as! Data).response { response, error in
        if let metadata = response {
            print("Uploaded file name: \(metadata.name)")
            print("Uploaded file revision: \(metadata.rev)")

            // Get file (or folder) metadata
        }
        if let error = error {
            switch error as! CallError<SwiftyDropbox.Files.UploadError> {
            case .routeError(let boxed, let requestId):
                switch boxed.unboxed {
                case .path(let failedPath):
                        //print("Failed update 2 path: \(failedPath)")
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("dbFileCreationError"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                        break

                    default:
                        //print("Unknown \(error)")
                        break
                    }
            case .internalServerError(let code, let message, let requestId):
                //print("InternalServerError[\(requestId)]: \(code): \(message)")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("dbInternalServerError"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                break
            case .badInputError(let message, let requestId):
                //print("BadInputError[\(requestId)]: \(message)")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("dbBadInputError"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                break
            case .authError(let authError, let requestId):
                //print("AuthError[\(requestId)]: \(authError)")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("dbAuthError"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                break
            case .rateLimitError(let rateLimitError, let requestId):
                //print("RateLimitError[\(requestId)]: \(rateLimitError)")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("dbRateLimitError"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                break
            case .httpError(let code, let message, let requestId):
                //print("HTTPError[\(requestId)]: \(code): \(message)")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("dbHTTPError"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                break
            default:
                break
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload a large(r) file (> 800MB) with this (gist) code (Swift 2.2) -->

https://gist.github.com/cnharris10/3d744ca13abd13d4d5bd3a363be16dff

See example screen shot below with another 150mb file uploaded in chunks of 1mb

[image]